# Saving a file with an URL as the name of the file using Python on Windows

Tags: python

I am having trouble with saving a file using Python on windows.

Here's the URL variable that stores the URL:

```
my_url = "https://example.com/some-page"
```

I want to remove the "https:" part and all the "/" from this string. This is what I tried:

```
filename = my_url.replace('https://', '')
filename = filename.replace('http://', '')
filename = filename.replace('/', '|') + ".txt"
```

I want to remove these characters as windows doesn't allow `:` and `/` characters as a file name.

The error that I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "123.py", line 28, in <module>
    f = open(filename, "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'example.com|some-page.txt'
```

I want to do this with multiple URLs so even though the actual link uses `https` I tried to remove the `http` too.

Comment: But it also doesn't allow `|` in the file name so you'll need a different replacement character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in `urllib` called `urllib.parse.quote` which removes special characters from urls and replaces them with their equivalent percent encoding.

> **urllib.parse.quote(string, safe='/', encoding=None, errors=None)**
>
> Replace special characters in string using the %xx escape. Letters, digits, and the characters '_.-' are never quoted. By default, this function is intended for quoting the path section of URL. The optional safe parameter specifies additional ASCII characters that should not be quoted — its default value is '/'.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character ("|") is not allowed in Windows filenames either. Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem :)

Here's what I did:

```
filename = my_url.replace('https://', '')
filename = filename.replace('http://', '')
filename = filename.replace('.', '_')
filename = filename.replace('-', '_')
filename = filename.replace('/', '_') + ".txt"
```

Thank you!

Comment: No need to replace `-` and `.`. Those are allowed.